# Связывание в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Задача состоит в привязке данных в XAML. Необходимо связать строковое поле в XAML разметке с полем одного из свойств контекста данных отображения. Поясню на примере:

```
class Person
{
    // ...
    public string Name
    { get; set;}
    public string Addres
    { get; set; }
    // ...
}
class PersonDataContext
{
    // ...
    public Person CurrentPerson
    { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

В XAML разметке такой код:

```
<!-- XAML -->
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource CurrentPerson}, Path=Name}" />
```

Сборка проходит успешно, но если попробовать запустить, то появляется ошибка, в которой говорится о невозможности приведения строки к типу `RelativeSource`. В чем ошибка? Может есть способ решить задачу по другому?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На самом деле все на много проще. Если вам надо связать поля свойства контекста данных в Xaml, то надо так и написать:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=CurrentPerson.Name}" />
```

На сколько мне известно, в xaml можно и к элементам массива обращаться. К примеру:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Persons[0].Name}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

А ошибка в том, что конструктор RelativeSource нужно передавать перечисление, указывающее направление движения относительно текущего элемента.